# Canvas drawImage is not accepting width and height

Tags: javascript, canvas

Image is getting created in full original size, even last two arguments `150, 150` are height and width `context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 150, 150);` in the code below:

```
function (file) { //uploaded files are always images
    var reader = new FileReader(); //FileReader for uploading files from local stroge.
    reader.onload = function () {
        var links = document.createElement('a'); //link when image is clicked 
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = reader.result; //src = url from uploaded file
        img.className = 'images'; //css -> .images { margin-top: 30px; padding: 30px; }
        img.onload = function () { //repaint image to 150 - 150 size with canvas, because setting width and height on image itself would just resize the image but I want to create new image with new size
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 150, 150) //draw image with canvas 
        }
        links.href = reader.result; // url from local storage needed  when image is clicked - 
        links.target = "_blank"; // open new blank page with original image
        links.appendChild(img); // image is appended to <a>
        document.body.appendChild(links); // <a> is appended to body, that body contains image thumbnail with a link linked to the image source
    }
    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); // read uploaded files url
    }
}
```

`img.onload` does not making any sense here. result is the same even when I remove it.

Comment: maybe context.drawImage(**this**, 0, 0, 150, 150);

Comment: No change, actually as you can see I'm uploading the image and all I want is to repaint the image with 150-150 size

Comment: **links.appendChild(img);** should be inside the image onLoad event after  **context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 150, 150);**

Comment: appendChild doesn't make any sense

Comment: you are appending the image BEFORE the onload event complete... and BEFORE the canvas manipulation.. perfect sense to me

Comment: that's what I've done after your comment. but no change. Image is still in full original size

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve. Do you just want to use FileReader to render a client-specified image on the canvas? What are you trying to achieve with that link?

Comment: If you read down the comments everything is clear. FileReader uploads images from local storage and every uploaded image should be repainted to dimensions 150 to 150 using canvas.

Comment: In the gods sake, does anyone can help?

Comment: The only comment in your question is `//reads the data as a URL` that's not what I call "clear". You are drawing on a new canvas but it is never appended, normal you don't see anything. There is no clear error message in your question. We can't guess what `file` is, nor where it does come from. **No we can't help you, until you do help us help you**

Comment: just check out whether that helps

Answer (score 1):

You are not drawing back the cropped image to your `<img>` tag... you will have to create two image Objects, let's call the first `originalImage`, and the second one `croppedImage`.

The one you will append to the document is `croppedImage`and `originalImage` will just stay in the cache.

When `originalImage` has loaded, you will paint it to a canvas, and then set `croppedImage` to the result of the canvas' `toDataURL()` method.

```js
var read = function() {
  var file = this.files[0];
  
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    
    var links = document.createElement('a');
    // this will be the appended image
    var croppedImage = new Image();
    // do your DOM stuff
    croppedImage.className = 'images';
    links.href = reader.result;
    links.target = "_blank";
    links.appendChild(croppedImage);
    document.body.appendChild(links);
    // create a buffer image object
    var originalImage = new Image();
    // set its load handler
    originalImage.onload = function() {
      // create a canvas
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      // set canvas width/height
      canvas.width = canvas.height = 150;
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      // draw the buffered image to the canvas at required dimension
      context.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, 150, 150);
      // set the appended to doc image's src to the result of the cropping operation
      croppedImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();

    }

    originalImage.src = reader.result;

  }
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
};

upload.onchange = read;
```

```css
.images {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" />
```

You could also have used only a single image object, but this would have required to reset the `onload` event in the `onload` event, to avoid an infinite loop, which is a little bit less clear :

```js
var read = function() {
  var file = this.files[0];
  
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    
    var links = document.createElement('a');

    var img = new Image();
    img.className = 'images';
    links.href = reader.result;
    links.target = "_blank";
    links.appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(links);


    img.onload = function() {
      //reset the onload event so it does fire in a loop
      img.onload = function(){return;};
      
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = canvas.height = 150;
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 150, 150);
      this.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    }

    img.src = reader.result;

  }
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
};

upload.onchange = read;
```

```css
.images {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function () {
    var links = document.createElement('a');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = reader.result;
    img.className = 'images';
    img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 150, 150);
        this.src = canvas.toDataURL(); // convert the canvas back to the image
        links.appendChild(this); // append the updated image to the document
    }
    links.href = reader.result;
    links.target = "_blank";

    document.body.appendChild(links);
}
if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
}
```

Comment: Image is disappearing just after creation in few milliseconds and the appending element holds url in base64 format which is super long and crashing the browser

Comment: so.. maybe you wish to display the canvas itself and not the image over your html document.. the user can't tell the difference

Comment: I want to display image created in canvas

Comment: I guess that this code dump is just applying what you said in comment. Then it makes no sense. `new Image()` does return "an HTMLImageElement instance just as document.createElement('img') would." You can already append it to the DOM directly after the constructor has been called, no need for it to have its src attribute set and even less to have its content loaded. you should not append this code in the load event : if you do change the src afterwards, the load event will fire again and it will append the `<img>` has the last child of the parent node again.

Comment: Kaiido, then do you know the solution?

Comment: @developer, no because I don't know the problem